# django rest_framework custom exception error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django rest_framework, And tried to create customized error reponse in django!.

[Django Rest Framework Exceptions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/)

After going through that, all seems to be pretty straight forward, but the import error raise when i try to add the custom exception.

Settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'project.restapi.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

> ImportError
>   Exception Value:
>   Could not import 'project.restapi.utils.custom_exception_handler' for API setting 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER'. AttributeError: module 'project.restapi.utils' has no attribute 'custom_exception_handler'

custom_exception_handler.py

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

    return response
```

model.py

```
class Users(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # call the original 'list' to get the original response
        response = super(Users, self).retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs) 

        response.data = {"collection": {"data": response.data},"statusCode":response.status_code,"version":"1.0"}
        # customize the response data
        if response is not None:
            return response
        else:
            # return response with this custom representation
            response.data = {"collection": {"data": response.data},"statusCode":response.status_code,"version":"1.0","error":response.exception}
            return response
```

So on the above model works fine, except when i try to hit the user which is not in the database should raise error - not found, so i tried to customise the not found to be meaningful to my own. that's it

I tried to sort out, but hard to do so!!,

Django Version: 2.1.5
Python - 3.7.0

Comment: This is probably an import/module problem. You should include on the question the contents of **project.restapi.utils**. Without that it's hard to tell what the problem is. You probably need to have an `__init__.py` file on that folder and import `custom_exception_handler` there.

Comment: posted the custom_exception_handler.py code,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `custom_exception_handler` resides in a file named `custom_exception_handler.py`. You can try changing the `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` setting to this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'project.restapi.utils.custom_exception_handler.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Comment: [DRF's setting implementation](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/settings.py#L182) would try to import `custom_exception_handler` function  (i.e. the part after the last dot) from `project.restapi.utils.custom_exception_handler`. In your attempt it was trying to import `custom_exception_handler` function from `project.restapi.utils`.

Comment: (val, setting_name, e.__class__.__name__, e) this actually matters a lot!!